# Crash with GCM libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-messaging

I need to include GCM push notification service (I cannot use FCM due to server dependency yet) to my project. I see this error when I follow google dev documentation:

> 04-18 12:09:37.206 17761-17761/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
>   04-18 12:09:37.208 17761-17761/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   04-18 12:09:37.211 17761-17761/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.sample.airwatchsdk, PID: 17761
>                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/com.sample.airwatchsdk-itMJY1a4DNFnw-ItRDDjiw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!classes68.dex)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source:3)
>                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   Blockquote

Can someone please help me with this?

My gradle dependencies:
App level:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Project level:

```
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.4.2'

        compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+"

        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2"

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
```

Comment: did you enable multidex?

Comment: Yes. I have multidex enabled.

Comment: Google has officially announced the deprecation for GCM. It is strongly advised that you proceed with using FCM now. IMHO, still choosing to implement GCM at this stage would be a factor that increases technical debt.